# Examples needed for open-source forums, blogs, wikis

Tags: php, blogs, wiki, forum

We are a small company developing a browser game. As planned we need a forum, wiki and a blog. The initial idea was to code everything by ourselves but time is short as always and we need to cut some corners. What we need is simple applications that have the general functionality. If you have used/developed something like that and it is free for use, we would appreciate sharing the source code(link).

Edit:
Clearly it is not the place to ask such a question. I just wanted some examples that you have used and liked, google can find a lot of stuff but cannot evaluate it for me. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Whatever happened to searching for these things on google?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_content_management_systems

Comment: You may want to look at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ as a more targeted forum for this question.

Comment: @mark I have huge respect for the people here, that is why I ask for their personal preferences. Google can show me the results but cannot evaluate the quality for me.

Comment: If you have huge respect for the people here, please don't ask questions that are off-topic here.

Comment: As I edited my post I said that this is not the right place for the question and I am sorry. But still the purpose of the site is to help fellow developers resolve their issues and I don't get all the grammar(code)-nazi stuff. Seriously guys we should help each other...

Comment: @chosta - It would be easier to answer your question if you'd posted requirements for the packages that you're interested in (eg must be OOP, must run on PHP4, forum must support threading, or blog must allow only registered users to post comments)... the question is too broad and comes down to arguments about personal preference. You end up with an enormous list of options with conflicting opinions on why X is considered better than Y. ceejayoz has given you a list of functionality comparison pages, which is a good starting point; and Kendrick has pointed you to the right place to ask.

Comment: I see, thank you for the comprehensive information. Ill try to be more accurate in my future questions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use open source CMS such as [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/), [Drupal](http://drupal.org) or [WordPress](http://wordpress.org)

[Joomla Wiki Components](http://www.onestopjoomla.com/extensions/wiki/)

[Joomla Forums](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/forum)

[Joomla Blogs](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/blog)

Answer (score 2):

phpBB
mediawiki
wordpress

Answer (score 2):

Wiki:
http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki

BBS/Forum:
http://www.phpbb.com/

Blog:
http://wordpress.org/

All free, easy to use and widely supported.

Comment: The Wiki article on Wikipedia lists the main, good, ones at the bottom by language type: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki_software

Answer (score 1):

[Wordpress](http://wordpress.org) is of course the most common blogging structure, I use it and they have a very good codex wiki to help out if you have questions. They also have a ton of plugins that can be added (from SEO to paging your blogs). The CSS and HTML is very easily modified. I, personally, use WordPress and it's pretty straight forward. [My website](http://www.jasonleodurbin.com). All of the websites I maintain use WordPress for their blogging structure.

[bbPress](http://bbpress.org/) is a solution to your forums. I don't know much about it, but it is from the same brain that co-founded WordPress. I expect that it would be as easy as Wordpress.

Of course [ning](http://www.ning.com/) is a solution if you want a community (not free). Just some options.